# Do I need to change my normal Django code when introducing Django Channels?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-channels, daphne, asgi

Hello I am a beginner in the python world, so I am still trying to understand the care when working with ASGI. I read some tutorials and documentation, as well as watched some videos on youtube. However, I was unsure on some points.

I have a small backend application using Django + Django Rest Framework.

My code is very trivial, composed of the most common concepts in the framework: views, serializers, models, urls, etc. In addition, I use a relational database.

My environment is this:

- Python 3.8
- Django 3
- Django Rest Framework 3.11

Now, I need to add support for WebSockets and I did the basic configuration described in the Django Channels tutorial:

- I installed Django Channels 2.4.0 (Daphene 2.5.0)
- Added 'channels' to INSTALLED_APPS
- I created a routing.py file with an empty ProtocolTypeRouter
- I added ASGI_APPLICATION to my settings.py
- I configured the asgi.py file to use channels
- At the moment, I have not configured any channel layers
- At the moment, I haven't created any WebSocket endpoint

After these configurations the runserver is using an ASGI development server and apparently my REST endpoints are all working.

Some questions:

- Considering that all my code is synchronous, wouldn't it be necessary to make any adjustments to it?
- This configuration above, already does all the magic necessary for my synchronous code to be executed safely in daphene considering that it is an ASGI server?
- Can I serve normal HTTP and WebSockets requests using only ASGI in a reliable and stable manner? Or, is it recommended to serve HTTP traffic using WSGI and leave only WebSockets traffic to daphene?
- Where exactly should care be taken regarding synchronous code?

Comment: Marlon, are you using django-channels alone, or the optional channel-layers component as well ?

Comment: For now, only django-channels, but soon we are thinking of introducing the channel layer with Redis.

Answer (score 1):

These are my answers based on previous experiences with Django Channels 2 ...

**1) Considering that all my code is synchronous, wouldn't it be necessary to make any adjustments to it?**

You can safely keep your existing sync code: no adjustments are required; just make sure to call the “sync version” of django-channels API (i.e. SyncConsumer instead of AsyncConsumer).

On the other hand, `Channel Layers` uses a different approach, and provides only an async version.
When the call is issued from sync code, you need to use the async_to_sync wrapper; for example:

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
    group, {
        "type": 'data_received',
        "content": data,
    })
```

**2) This configuration above, already does all the magic necessary for my synchronous code to be executed safely in daphene considering that it is an ASGI server?**

The single missing details is (in settings file):

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'
```

**3) Can I serve normal HTTP and WebSockets requests using only ASGI in a reliable and stable manner? Or, is it recommended to serve HTTP traffic using WSGI and leave only WebSockets traffic to daphene?**

With Channels 2, you can safely choose to use Daphne for both HTTP and WebSockets requests, since Daphne will auto-negotiates between HTTP and WebSocket; this is what I usually do in my projects.

Splitting HTTP and WebSocket traffic, thus:

- running standard HTTP requests through a WSGI server
- using Daphne (or uvicorn) only for things WSGI cannot do, like WebSockets, HTTP long-polling or other IoT protocols

is possible, but entirely optional.